# Cannot read property 'handleClick' of undefined when using map

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to make a table row function like a `Link` with `react-router`.

I keep getting the error `Cannot read property 'handleClick' of undefined`

```
handleClick(user) {
   this.router.transitionTo('index', user);
}

render(){
   var userNodes = this.props.posts.map(function(user, i){
       return (
         <tr onClick={() => this.handleClick(user)}>
           <Td>{user.postId}</Td>
           <Td>{user.title}</Td>
           <Td>{user.body}</Td>   
         </tr>
       )
   });
...
```

Answer (score 4):

Use arrow function as `map` callback to preserve component context (otherwise `this` inside the callback will not point to the component instance):

```
render(){
   var userNodes = this.props.posts.map((user, i) => {
       return (
         <tr onClick={() => this.handleClick(user)}>
           <Td>{user.postId}</Td>
           <Td>{user.title}</Td>
           <Td>{user.body}</Td>   
         </tr>
       )
   });
```

Answer (score 1):

Its a `binding` issue, you need to `bind` the context otherwise `this` will not point to the react component. Either use `.bind(this)` with `function` or use `arrow function` to avoid this kind of problem. Use this:

```
render(){
   var userNodes = this.props.posts.map(function(user, i){
       return (
         <tr onClick={() => this.handleClick(user)}>
           <Td>{user.postId}</Td>
           <Td>{user.title}</Td>
           <Td>{user.body}</Td>   
         </tr>
       )
   }.bind(this));
```

Or this:

```
render(){
   var userNodes = this.props.posts.map((user, i) => {
       return (
         <tr onClick={() => this.handleClick(user)}>
           <Td>{user.postId}</Td>
           <Td>{user.title}</Td>
           <Td>{user.body}</Td>   
         </tr>
       )
   });
```

Check the working example:

```js
class App extends React.Component{

  handleClick(user){
    console.log(user);
  }

  render(){
   var data = [0,1,2,3,4].map((user, i) => {
       return (
         <tr onClick={() => this.handleClick(user)}>
           <td>{user}</td>
           <td>{user}</td>
           <td>{user}</td>   
         </tr>
       )
   });
   
   return(
      <table>
         <thead>
            <th>A</th>
            <th>B</th>
            <th>C</th>
         </thead>
         <tbody>
            {data}
         </tbody>
      </table>
   )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id='app'/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to bind it.

```
var userNodes = this.props.posts.map(function(user, i){}.bind(this));
```