# ReactJS - TypeError undefined class when passing method over multiple child classes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrow-functions

I got the error `Unable to read property moveToExtraDeck of undefined` on MainDeck class although I do `bind` the class to method in its constructor. This is the parent `MainDeck` class:

```
//Omitted import statements ...

export default class MainDeck extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.moveToExtraDeck = this.moveToExtraDeck.bind(this);
        this.state = ...
    }

    moveToExtraDeck() {
        alert('This card cannot reside in Extra Deck.');
    }

    render () {
        return (
            <div class="ui card">
                ....
                <div class="extra content">
                    <div class="ui stackable grid">
                    {
                        this.state.cards.map(function(card, i) {
                            return <Card card={ card } deck={ 'main' } moveToExtra={ this.moveToExtraDeck } />;
                        }, this) //Just bind the class here as suggested
                    }
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

And this class `Card` is the child of the `MainDeck` class:

```
//Omitted import statements ...

export default class Card extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = ...
    }

    render () {
        return (
            <div class="ui card">
                ....
                <div class="extra content">
                    <Button deck={ this.state.deck } onClick={ this.props.moveToExtra } />
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Finally the Button class is the child of `Card` class:

```
//Omitted import statements ...

export default class Button extends React.Component {
    render () {
        return (
            <div class="ui simple dropdown">
                <button
                    class={ this.props.deck === 'extra' ? 'disabled item' : 'item' }
                    onClick={ this.props.onClick }>Extra Deck</button>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

I am confused if my code is an anti-pattern, and what has been wrong when I pass method over multiple child classes making undefined parent class.

Update: I have edited the code as suggested, and bind `MainDeck` class to `map`. It can display the page. The error isn't thrown when I click the button but no alert is display. I don't know why.

Comment: `I got the error` Where exactly, what is **?

Comment: Can you please explain how did you got the error?

Comment: There is a syntax error in your code `<Button deck={ this.state.deck } onClick={ () => this.props.moveToExtra() />` should be like this `<Button deck={ this.state.deck } onClick={ () => this.props.moveToExtra()} />`

Comment: check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43159599/5185595), you need to bind map callback method, `this.state.cards.map((card, i) => {....}`, to access this (class instance) inside that.

Comment: This is not an exact duplicate, what he is trying to do was. He just sends his function as a prop to his child components. In that he wants to access the function from chid component.  @LK Phuc Nguyen , just replace the card components onClick with onclick={this.props.moveToExtra}. this will fix your issue

Comment: This is not an exact duplicate, what he is trying to do was. He just sends his function as a prop to his child components. In that he wants to access the function from chid component.  @LK Phuc Nguyen , just replace the **Button's onClick of Card Component with onclick={this.props.moveToExtra}**. this will fix your issue

Comment: @Jeeva Thank you, Jeeva! I edit it like your suggestion. It got better. Formerly it just threw the error, the page was unable to render. Now it displays the page, then I click the button, it throws the error as above.

Comment: Use arrow function at button's onclick **onClick={ () =>this.props.onclick()}** this will fix yours

Comment: I have tried both ways `onClick={ () =>this.props.onclick() }` and `onClick={ this.props.onclick }`. Both of them works. I just test the `alert` in `MainDeck` by `moveToExtra={ () => alert('My Test') }`. Now it displays the alert when I click buttons. But when I place `alert` in a separate function, it doesn't work.

Comment: @LK Phuc Nguyen, can you try with MainDeck component's rendering of Card component like this.    this.state.cards.map( (card, i) => { return <Card card={ card } deck={ 'main' } moveToExtra={ this.moveToExtraDeck } />;
})  use this as reference (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30148827/this-is-undefined-inside-map-function-reactjs)

Comment: @Jeeva It's working now. Yesterday it was wrong because of a typo in my code. Thank you so much for your helps.